# How can I write a stored procedure which accepts a variable number of bind parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to modify my SELECT statement as follows

```
SELECT blob_data from table where id = ?
```

TO

```
SELECT blob_data from table where id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

```
TABLE
ID            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
BLOB_DATA     BLOB
```

The problem with this approach is that when executing the loop in Java, I may have less than 5 IDs. I want to write a stored procedure+CallableStatement instead of a PreparedStatement to fire the **second** query. [I thought of writing 5 different stored procedures which accept 1 to 5 arguments, but I think there should be a better approach!]

How can I write a stored procedure which accepts a variable number of bind parameters? Also, how will the Java and corresponding Oracle code look?

I will be very grateful for help with this code

Comment: Just a stupid idea. If the caller specifies NULLs for the missing IDs, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use collections instead, for example:

```sql
SELECT blob_data from table where id IN (select * from table(?))
```

So you will need just to bind collection.
Create your own collection type and use it in your queries, for example:

```
create type number_table as table of number;
```

Just for testing purpose (not production) you can use internal sys.ku$_objnumset (table of number) or sys.odcinumberlist(varray of number)

Comment: I do not know about collections. Is there source code you can point me to or better still, could you please add source code here?